# XSS when <, > and " are escaped?

Tags: web-application, attacks, xss, appsec

I'm pentesting a website that has a reflected XSS, or at least a vector for a reflection, but the issue is the following :

- It escapes `<`, `>`, `"` to their HTML entities, but not `&`, `)` or `(`.
- You are not in a tag, so you have to create your own.

It's not the first time that I see implementations of this sort. Express.js has this by default for example. Are implementations like these safe from XSS?

Comment: Where exactly is it reflected? I.e. is it inside an attribute or text node or script tags, or style, etc..?

Comment: I believe this is well documented.

Comment: In addition to other answers, also see this about "mXSS attacks":
http://www.reddit.com/r/netsec/comments/1skr62/owasp_appsec_eu_2013_how_mxss_attacks_change/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, that's not necessarily sufficient.  There are *many* XSS vectors that can potentially still be applied, depending upon where the injection point is.

Some examples:

- Injection into unquoted attribute values
- Injection into attribute values quoted with a single quote (`'` instead of `"`)
- Injection into CSS
- Injection into Javascript
- Injection into comments

... and lots more.  You need to do context-sensitive escaping, and you definitely need to escape at minimum `<`, `>`, `"`, `'`, plus some more in some contexts.  Go spend some time on the OWASP site; there's tons written there, and this is explained in great detail.

Comment: +1 (While you are right, I do not see where an escaped `>` would allow getting out of an HTML comment.)

Comment: @freddyb, yeah, it's tricky.  For comments, the key character is `-`, which has an interesting effect inside HTML comments (most people don't know about the surprising behavior of HTML/SGML comments).  Such attacks are not easy and probably only possible in rare circumstances, but it's better to not inject dynamic values inside comments.

Comment: I fully agree. Do you have any weird findings with regard to comments though?

Answer (score 2):

sometimes they escape "alert " parameter too, then you can use something like "onMouseOver" etc and you can find the full link here. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet  (try xss locators)

moreover you can use %3C insead of < and so on... 
try url encoding etc.

and if the text is encoded in the background, you xss may not work...